# Amplifier for voltage measurement

Tags: voltage, amplifier

I need an amplifier to measure the difference of voltage of 48V battery. As I were seaching, I found the [AD8206](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8206.pdf%20%22AD8206) from Analog Devices with High common-mode voltage range from −2 V to +65 V operating but used mainly and recommended for current shunt applications. Can I still use this amplifier to measure the differential voltage on my battery?

Comment: What differential voltage on your battery?

Comment: I have no idea what kind of battery you have, but if it consists of several cells in series. Will it not be better to use something like this http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/680412fc.pdf , The LTC6804 is build for monitoring battery packs and can easily reach your desired voltage.

Comment: The gain of 20 of that amplifier doesn't sound very suitable for this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers are all in the datasheet. Mostly in Table 1.

http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8206.pdf

1)  The maximum power supply voltage is 5.5V.
  2)  The amplifier output voltage can go to VCC - 0.3V (which is 5.2V).
  3)  The gain of the amplifier is fixed at 20V/V.
  4)  Therefore the maximum difference you can measure is 5.2V / 20 = 0.26V.

But analog devices has plenty of other difference amplifiers that would work.

The LT6375 is pretty good.